# how to make this automatically reveal the text without the button?

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate

how can I make the animation below to reveal the text without playing the button?
Thank you.

```
const reveal = document.querySelector('.reveal-wrapper')

const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')

playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
reveal.classList.add('reveal-wrapper-ani')
setTimeout(() => {
 reveal.classList.remove('reveal-wrapper-ani')
}, 1000)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried just taking the function out, so you are just left with the add call without having to wait for a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the event listener and apply its actions on the loading script:

```
const reveal = document.querySelector('.reveal-wrapper')

reveal.classList.add('reveal-wrapper-ani')
setTimeout(() => {
 reveal.classList.remove('reveal-wrapper-ani')
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks Celso and Haworth. I tried that, it works but then it auto-disappears again. Here's the codepin URL https://codepen.io/tomv-m/pen/MWWPygd   any suggestions?

Comment: https://codepen.io/BrainClouder/pen/GRqXWvd
Here, you don't need to change the script. Just added the `.reveal-wrapper-ani` class to your main element, then I added the property `forwards` in the animation class to tell CSS to maintain the last state of the animation.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode